# Angular CDK Virtual Scrolling remove item from list

Tags: angular, list, datasource, angular8, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

In the Angular CDK virtual Scrolling I'm using a list and adding items to the list from a button and it works. I'm having another button to remove item from the list but the UI is not refreshed with the removed content.

```
list: any[];


<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport autoSize class="list-container lg" itemSize="5">
    <ul *cdkVirtualFor="let item of list; let i = index;  
          let lastItem = last" class="list-group-item list-group-items list-group">
        {{item}}
    </ul>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

**Adding to list**

```
const item = 4;
this.list = [...this.list, item];
```

How to **remove** the item from the list and **refresh** the view?

**Note** : I'm using non-observable data source.

Answer (score 1):

just create new array without the item that you don't need. for example like this

```
this.list = this.list.filter((item, index) => index !== indexToDelete)
```